# Examples of Chordal Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on a problem about Chordal graphs and I want to check my statement for good amount of Chordal graphs using Sage. I have come across very few examples of chordal graphs here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChordalGraph.html

is there any other places where I can found more examples of chordal graphs or can you tell any collection of graphs which are always chordal?

Some useful links are also heartly welcomed.

Thanks for your valuable timing.

Comment: It would help to post the problem you are working on, for context...

Comment: @Math1000 sorry. Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them :)

Answer (score 2):

Trees are chordal, so are interval graphs, split graphs.
You can check out subclasses of chordal graphs at http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_32.html

Also, you can start with any graph and make it chordal by triangulating it: fix an ordering of the vertices, say $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$. For $i=1$ to $n$ do: make the vertices in $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1}\} \cap N(v_i)$ a clique.